# How to merge query in wordpress with different arguments

Tags: merge, wordpress

```
$all = array(
 'post_type' => array("pwpd_poll","pwpd_infog"),
 'posts_per_page' => wp_is_mobile() ? 3 : 7,
 'orderby' => 'post_date',
 'order' => 'DESC'
);

$news = array(
 'post_type' =>array('pwpd_news'),
 'meta_query' => $meta_query_par,
 'date_query'=>array(
    array(
     'year'  => $today['year'],
     'month' => $today['mon'],
     'day'   => $today['mday'],
    )
  )
);
```

the problem is the $news output is always in the end of the loop the "orderby" doesnt seem to be working and also the "posts_per_page" is not exact in the output.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to achieve as it's unclear with this small explaination.

Comment: orderby should be by `date`, not `post_date` :-)